# remove a list from a given list without having knowledge of the list you want to remove

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, pandas-groupby

am trying to remove a list from a given list without having knowledge of the list you want to remove.

suppose :

```
l = [[1,2,3], [234, 33,3], [as, dd, ds]]
```

I have picked a list randomly from a list using the code

```
output = np.random.choice(range(0,len(l), 2, replace = False)

output = [0,1]
```

how do I delete the `output` from the original list `l` ?

Comment: `l.remove(output)`?

Comment: I have changed the question, can you you check it now @hpaulj

Answer (score 1):

The `.remove` method should work.

```
l.remove(output)
```

**EDIT**

I supose that the `output` contains the indexes of the lists that you want to remove. If this is the case you can do it:

```
l = [x for i, x in enumerate(l) if i not in output]
```

and your result will be:

```
l = [['as', 'dd', 'ds']]
```

Comment: I have changed the question, can you you check it now